# openssl s_client, what does s/i mean?

Tags: ssl, openssl

So I've tried to  find the answer on Google or in the man pages, but searching for the meaning of an identifier that's one letter appears to be impossible.

If I run the following:

```
openssl s_client -connect google.ca:443 -showcerts
```

I get this:

```
 2 s:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
   i:/C=US/O=Equifax/OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

What do the `s` and `i` values mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### What does s/i mean?

> Each certificate is presented as a **Subject** and an **Issuer**. The Subject
>   is the thing the certificate is supposed to represent, and the Issuer
>   is the issuing Certificate Authority.

- `s` stands for **Subject**
- `i` stands for **Issuer**.

---

> **Certificate Subject and Issuer**
>
> Each certificate is presented as a Subject and an Issuer. The Subject
>   is the thing the certificate is supposed to represent, and the Issuer
>   is the issuing Certificate Authority. For example here’s certificate 0
>   (the server certificate) from this chain:
>
> ```
>  0 s:/1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3=US/1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.2=
>      Washington/businessCategory=Private Organization/serialNumber=
>      600413485/C=US/postalCode=98052/ST=Washington/L=Redmond/
>      street=1 Microsoft Way/O=Microsoft Corporation/OU=MSCOM
>      /CN=www.microsoft.com
>    i:/C=US/O=Symantec Corporation/OU=Symantec Trust Network
>      /CN=Symantec Class 3 EV SSL CA - G3
> ```
>
> You can see the certificate number (zero) then s: meaning Subject: and
>   i: meaning Issuer. It follows then that the Issuer of certificate 0
>   should be the Subject of certificate 1, as we want to verify if the
>   Issuer is valid; and so it is:
>
> ```
>  1 s:/C=US/O=Symantec Corporation/OU=Symantec Trust Network
>      /CN=Symantec Class 3 EV SSL CA - G3
>    i:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=(c) 2006
>      VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only/CN=VeriSign Class 3
>      Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
> ```

Source [Five Essential OpenSSL Troubleshooting Commands](http://movingpackets.net/2015/03/16/five-essential-openssl-troubleshooting-commands/)